# What are the 85 types of Jing?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In *Avatar: The Last Airbender* Bumi tells Aang that there are 85 types of Jing, though we are only told 3 of them at the time; Positive, Negative, and Neutral Jing.   Do we know what the other 82 Jings are?

Comment: I bet Bumi made up 83 of them on the spot. And yes, I mean 83, not 82.

Answer (score 1):

Within the world of Avatar, no other Jing types are known. However, *A:TLA* did not originate the concept. Like many elements of the franchise, Jing comes from Asian culture, meaning "energy" in Chinese.

[Real Jings include](http://www.denner.org/reinhard/neijia/terms/listOfJings.html) Listening, Sticking, Following, Neutralizing, Borrowing, Drawing-up, Uprooting, Sinking, Controlling, Open-up, Close-up, Deflecting, Rubbing, Twisting, Rolling, Spiral, Cutting, Interrupting, Inches, Fine, Vibrating Bouncing, Vibrating, Folding, and Distance.

[Another site lists](https://www.cleartaichi.com/blog/jing-energy-503.html) Explosive,
Heavy/Rooted/Sinking, Silk reeling,
Peng,
Absorbing,
Pulling silk,
Electrical,
Magnetic,
Listening, Empty force,
Short/Inch or less, Unbending Energy,
Following,
Neutralizing, Borrowing, Rolling/Folding, Spiral, Cold,
Vibrating, and
Floating.

Perhaps some combination of these Jings exist in the world of Avatar as well.